# I am getting configure: error: *** GLIB >= 1.2.2 not installed - please install first ***

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, glib, xmms2

I am using Debian Kali Linux 2.0 64 bit and am trying to install xmms player. 
I executed ./configure and I got the configure error (please see heading).  After searching on the net I saw that 
libgtk1.2 is no longer supported, You need to install libgtk2.0
. So, I issued the following command

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0 --fix-missing
```

Now I executed I went to the xmms directory and executed `./configure`, but I still get the following message

```
 checking for pthread.h... yes
    checking for glib-config... no
    checking for GLIB - version >= 1.2.2... no
    *** The glib-config script installed by GLIB could not be found
    *** If GLIB was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
    *** your path, or set the GLIB_CONFIG environment variable to the
    *** full path to glib-config.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

But it's easier to install xmms from an archive package.

Comment: Is there some registration/restart step required after installing this package to get glib-config to be available? I'm still getting the same glib-config error after installing it. (This is on a totally different project, but failing for the exact same error.)